# Nokogiri producing different results on heroku?

Tags: ruby, heroku, nokogiri

I'm having a very strange problem and I'd appreciate help tracking it down.

I'm using the nokogiri gem to parse some html, and I am parsing a file which has a weird character in it. Not entirely sure what this character is, in vim it shows as ^Q.

On my own computer, everything works fine, however on heroku it inserts a `</body></html><html>` when it hits the character and selectors only return the elements before the weird character.

To illustrate:
`Nokogiri::HTML( open("http://thoms.net.nz/e2.html")).css("body div").count` is 1 on heroku, and two on my computer. - The file containing this character can be downloaded from http://thoms.net.nz/e2.html.

Both my computer and heroku are running nokogiri 1.5.5 with ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: I guess this is a little unclear, sorry. The problem/question I'm having is that when running on heroku, the nokogiri library is producing incorrect results for this file which contains a weird character, but the same file works fine on my computer.

Comment: Can you show a minimal sample of the HTML that causes the problem? Without a sample of the HTML and an example of the code you are using, we are only guessing about an answer. As is, a HTML document can have multiple `<html>...</html>` blocks. It's unconventional, but I've seen it before.

Comment: the HTML is on my webserver, and the URL is in the question. Not the easiest to post here as it contains a weird character.

Comment: The html is broken. Differences will have more to do with the libxml version than the nokogiri/ruby version. Do nokogiri -v to see the libxml version.

Comment: Ah - That must be it. Heroku is running libxml 2.7.6, my machine has 2.7.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `^Q` is a software control character (XON), which isn't supposed to be in HTML. I suspect its unexpected presence is confusing both Nokogiri and Heroku, but in different ways.

HTML documents from the wilds of the internet can be corrupted in any numbers of ways. I've seen all sorts of garbage in them, and if I couldn't make sense of it using iconv or a Unicode transliteration, I'd resort to a quick global search and replace to remove anything not in the normal ASCII range before further processing.

---

In Ruby, global search and replace uses `String#gsub`.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html.gsub("\u0011", ''))
```

Comment: Can you suggest a good way of doing that filtering? This file isn't actually from the internet, it's been converted from a pdf with pdftohtml, so even more scope for general weirdness. It's still very strange that the same software running on heroku behaves differently to what it does locally, but I guess I don't have to fix that problem if I just filter the input first.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I will go with running the tr command like so: tr -dc '[:print:]'  < input.html > output.html  - so that it won't get tripped up by other weird characters as well.

Comment: You can do it from the command-line, or you can use Ruby's `gsub` or `tr` methods. They're all going to be equivalent for your needs.